# Options for deploying an interface for a museum exhibit?

Tags: macos, presentation, kiosk

We are building an companion presentation that will be displayed on computer screens next to a museum exhibit. I believe the machines are going to be running OSX (no touchscreens) and the users will need a mouse at minimum.

Does anyone have an recommendations for what environment to build in (flash, air, web, cocoa, etc) that will allow us to restrict access to the computer itself? Our main concern is with people alt-tabbing, command-q'ing, command-option-escape'ing, etc etc etc. Anything that will let them exit the presentation and access the main system is a major issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is called "Kiosk mode":

http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.19/19.12/KioskModeFeatures/index.html

Also, I would avoid giving the users a mouse. Mice *will* get destroyed in such exhibits over time. A better option might be a touchpad. I don't know for sure, but I would imagine they will have a longer lifespan in a display. I know trackballs used to be very popular for kiosks but the ones I've seen look like specially purchased devices, not the standard Kensington ones you get at the shop around the corner...

Comment: Gah, 'kiosk' was the word I was trying to think of but couldn't quite get it off my tongue (fingertips?). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

OS X has support for various [kiosk modes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/KioskMode/Introduction/Introduction.html) which you can trigger from pretty much any programming environment.  Something Web-based seems like a good strategy since it doesn't limit you much.  Opera has [kiosk support](http://www.opera.com/support/mastering/kiosk/) (which I haven't used) as does [iCab](http://www.icab.de/).  There are also some purpose-designed kiosk browsers such as [Plainview](http://www.barbariangroup.com/software/plainview) and [wKiosk](http://www.app4mac.com/software/product_details.php?item_id=3).

Comment: I've used plainview for presentations before and didn't realize it had full kiosk support. Thanks! Tried to upvote but I have less than 15 rep points :(

Comment: s'ok :-) Good luck with your project.